# What collections does jpa return?

Tags: java, list, jpa, eclipselink

Does JPA ( Eclipselink in this case) always  return IndirectList where Entity have a List? 
Is ok that list or It should be converted to another list( maybe linkedlist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Analysis

If we look at EclipseLink's [IndirectList's API](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/indirection/IndirectList.html), it says:

> To use an IndirectList: declare the appropriate instance variable with type IndirectList (jdk1.1) or Collection/List/Vector (jdk1.2).
>
> TopLink will place an IndirectList in the instance variable when the
>   containing domain object is read from the datatabase. With the first
>   message sent to the IndirectList, the contents are fetched from the
>   database and normal Collection/List/Vector behavior is resumed.

If we view [IndirectList sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/toplink.essentials/toplink-essentials/2.1-60/oracle/toplink/essentials/indirection/IndirectList.java), we will see, that all the work is delegated to it's original collection, just like API says.

## Answers

> Does JPA ( Eclipselink in this case) always return IndirectList where Entity have a List?

Yes, it always does return your specified collection wrapped with IndirectList. Since it delegates all its internal work to the wrapped collection, it preserves the way it works.

> Is ok that list or It should be converted to another list( maybe
>   linkedlist)?

Yes, it is okay to use IndirectList. You don't convert, you just define any type of collection you want and don't worry about IndirectList, since it is managed transparently.

Comment: Nicer answer than mine to be honest. +1

Comment: Great answer.  One addition is that EclpseLink will use indirectList or other IndirectContainer implementation when the collection is lazy loaded.  Eagerly fetched relationships should use a java Collection implementation type by default. EclipseLink can be customized to use which ever collection implementation required when building your entities.

Comment: How we can customize which ever collection implementation required?

Answer (score 2):

Since `List` is an interface the JPA provider is free to return any implementation. EclipseLink rerurns an `IndirectList` where a `List` is used. This is perfectly fine since the `IndirectList` is a `List`.

For the record or for future reference, it is generally best practice to use interfaces with JPA.

Comment: I spent some time searching through the JPA 2.1 spec for a word or two that comments on this explicitly, without no luck. Have you found a passage?

Comment: @MartinAndersson I am not a JPA user anymore, but I'll take a shot at it. I don't think this will be in the JPA spec, you'll have a better chance looking in the documentation of implementations (EclipseLink, Hibernate, etc.). `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList` is EclipseLink specific.

Comment: What is it that you program nowadays?

Comment: @MartinAndersson Python, but that's off topic I guess ;-)